# How do I get the script to a database view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I lost the script for a view that I created. Can I retrieve / recreate the script from the database using management studio?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select the View in the Object Explorer, right click, and select Script View as -> Create to -> New Query Editor Window. That will create a script to create the view in a new window.

Erick

Answer (score 20):

You can also retrieve this information by querying the sys.sql_modules dynamic management view:

Here's an example:

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
SELECT DEFINITION
  FROM sys.sql_modules  
 WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('HumanResources.vEmployee')
```

Answer (score 4):

Another small way if anyone want to:

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id('HumanResources.vEmployee'))
```